# Could not load file or assembly EntityFramework in DotNetNuke

Tags: entity-framework, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a old module in DotNetNuke. I used EF 5 in my project:

[image: EF]

I added module to DotNetNuke and it worked properly. But when I add new module that requierd to EF 6 my module gives me an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference.

When installing this new module EntityFramework 6 dll file will be replaced with old version (Version=5.0.0.0) file and this causes old module doesn't work.

I read many post for solving this problem but I can't find a way for this issue.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your web.config

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
      <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="bin/EntityFramework-6.1.3/EntityFramework.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework.SqlServer" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
      <codeBase version="6.0.0.0" href="bin/EntityFramework-6.1.3/EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

You have to add a folder called EntityFramework-6.1.3 into bin folder then add two follow dll to that 
1-EntityFramework.dll
2-EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to web.config

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.1.3.0" newVersion="6.1.3.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```